# the total(us) and percentage of cpu trace are wrong in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-profiler

Using the same trace file, every time you reload it, the percentage and total time data of the same method in the profile will change. This is abnormal.

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4

Comment: Can you open a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708&s=modified_time:descfirst and attach the trace file or screenshots for the Android Studio team to investigate? Thanks!

Comment: @YiYang it's here, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209837880